# OnPaint events order

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls, gdi+

I developed some components with their own `OnPaint`-override where I draw them.

I now added a status panel which is designed to overlap topmost with part of my form. I use a alpha-blended color to *gray out* the underlying controls and display a text on it.

Unfortunately some of my underlying custom controls paint themselves after the status bar and so draw themselves above the status bar. Debugging I found out that first the status bar on paint event was called, later the paint event of the underlying controls.

How can I make sure the proper order is used to paint?

When underlying components draw themselves the components infront of them should always be automatically invalidate so they redraw themselves but that is not happing. I also called `SendToFront` on the statusbar but that did not helper neither. So I am also asking what is the proper mechanism to maintain the order and how do the core components handle that.

**Edit**: I also run in this problem: With every run of my `OnPaint`-event my overlay gets more and more opaque because it draws with *alpha=128--red* again and again on itself.

Comment: When do you call `SendToFront` on the status bar?

Comment: After creation and again after I added the other controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eliminate external factors (like variations between XP, Vista, Win7), you could:

- blend the "status panel" graphics onto each control in their OnPaint handlers, so you don't need to mess about with a semi-transparent status window to achieve the desired display.
- use one opaque control (essentially the status panel) and render the final image you want into it by compositing the graphics from the individual controls, which would elimimnate any uncertainty over how the rendering process will operate. This would mean that you'd have to add custom click handling, but that's usually a fairly trivial addition - one easy way around this is to put the main "display control" behind a set of invisible controls (the buttons) so that all the click handling can work as normal, but the painting is delegated to a single control.

Comment: The first solution sounds like I tell every control on the form to draw part of the status panel after their own painting. This leads to the question how to get these parts as they might not be simple rectangle. I am not sure if I understand the second solution. Clicking is not an issue at the moment.

Comment: Are you using a semi-transparent [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czke9azk.aspx), a semitransparent [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk5b13s4(v=VS.100).aspx), or are you just overdrawing the screen area of the controls? It sounds like you're overdrawing, which would cause the problems you have described.

Comment: The form is opaque. The control for the status bar should be semitransparent. `CreateParams` is overridden to set `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`. `OnPaintBackground` is implemented but empty. `OnPaint` draws a rectangle with a `SolidBrush` created from ´Color.FromArgb`. Is that the wrong way?

Comment: Yes, that's wrong way.  The only way to make it reliable is to overlay your form with another form that uses TransparencyKey to make itself transparent.

Comment: Using a transparent form infront of my form for that soundslike eliminating all problems. But then I think on how to make its position synchronized with the main form and how to pass click to the underlying main form. Do you have any example @HansPassant ?

Comment: Meanwhile I got it to work that underlying controls notify the status bar to repaint it. But this leads to the problem that when there are two underlying controls, there is a statusbar-repaint for both of them. Making the alpha-effect on one of them lesser than on the other. This is because one of them is overdrawn once, the other twice. This keeps generating issues and I am still thinking about Hans' solution.

Comment: @Hans Passant : How can I keep that form topmost within my application but not topmost within windows?

Comment: Use the Show(owner) overload.  Keep them together with the LocationChanged event.  Check my answer here for sample code: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/3087655c-bd50-4408-9c55-dd179e442675/

Comment: I now solved it with the OnPaint event and taking the ClipRectangle into correct account. This works better in my case than examples with overlay forms. Therefore accepted this answer for guiding the way with it and its comments.